# OpenGL Passing variable to Shader

Tags: c++, opengl

I am doing an assignment for an OpenGl course and I can't seem to get my program to pass a variable to the vertex shader. I'm trying to pass my_bool so that when I press a key in the program, it toggles my_bool from true to false. The vertex shader should then pick a colour based on the boolean. But right now it doesn't respond when I press the key. What am I doing wrong?

I have this in my program.

```
bool wire = true;
void wireFrameMode() {
    if(wire) {
        wire = false;

        my_bool = 1.0;
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(programID,"my_bool"), my_bool);
    }
    else {
        wire = true;
        my_bool = 0.0;
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(programID,"my_bool"), my_bool);
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
    render();
}
```

Then in the vertex shader I have:

```
uniform float my_bool;
uniform vec3 wireColour = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
uniform vec3 wireColour2 = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
out vec4 fragmentColor;
// other variables for positioning

void main(){    

    // Some code for vertex positions

    if(my_bool == 1.0) {
        fragmentColor = vec4(wireColour, 1.0);
    }
    else {
        fragmentColor = vec4(wireColour2, 1.0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post the part of code where you initialize your shader? In addition, in your code it isn't binded to a shader. ""glUseProgram(programID)""

Comment: Also, note that you can actually put "uniform bool my_bool;" in the shader, and update it with glUniform1i() (for integer types). No need to use a float.